# Not able to scroll in iOS using <embed> HTML

Tags: html, ios, css, web, embed

I have a long website that I am embedding on another website. The below code works great on desktop browsers, but does not work on tablet or mobile.

On iOS, it is impossible to scroll as I attempt to move up and down the page. On desktop, there is no issue.

**Question: How can I correct the code below so that scrolling always works in any browser?**

---

*Code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
         html, body, embed {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         display: block;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <embed src="http://www.example.com">
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the  tag to include a scrollable webpage in another page. Same as your experience, the embedded page would scroll fine on desktop, but not on iOS. I switched to an iframe which does allow scrolling of the iframed content on both desktop and iOS:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;height:450px;" id="my">
    <iframe src="https://www.example.com" style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; border: none;" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess OP knows this already. But he's asking about embed. I think i know the reason why he's trying with embed. Mine is that Safari iOS doesn't return anything but 0 when getting scrollTop. I found that by using embed, at least it returns the scrollTop, but not possible to scroll within the embed tag. This is driving me CRAZY